# How to put "UP" my wlan0 Raspberry PI 4

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-4

I have a simple probleme but i'm a novice on the Raspberry pi.
Currently i have a Raspberry Pi 4 and i want to connect it to my wifi.
I use rapbian less desktop and at the start my twice network was down, 
i succeeded to up eth0 when i have connecte RJ45
but now when i try to connect my Raspberry pi to the wifi i don't found tuto to up wlan0
If someone have the issue and the solution i'm hope to speak whith it.
sorry  for my english if it is bad, i'm frensh.
Thanx for your time

my wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
 #ctrl_interface_group=0
ap_scan=1
update_config=1
 #country=FR

network={
          ssid="devolo"
          psk=lots of numbers and letters
}
```

Thanx for your time

Comment: See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) NOTE **In particular** without `country` WiFi on Pi4 is disabled!

Answer (score 1):

Your wpa_supplicant file should be something like :

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=FR

network={
    ssid="wifi name"
    psk="password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

key_mgmt is the type of security your wifi is using